# mysql temporal year

Tags: mysql, sql, database, temporal

I'm having trouble with the modeling and implementing of "temporal" events in my championship db.

I have three entity: player, team, transfer, championship and I want to track the players' transfer during a championship ( a player can be transferred to another team during a championship)

```
championship(id_championship*, name, year*)
player (id_player*, name, number, id_team*)
team (id_team, name)
transfer (id_player*, id_team_from*, id_team_to*, transfer _date)
```

thanks.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: using the enties like I posted I cannot store a players trasfert during a championship. I need to track something like a period a players belongs to a team.

Comment: With your actual tables structure, you can actually track periods where players belongs to a team.  So no problem here for me? Are you looking for the query to do that?

Comment: actually yes it could help. thanks. I'm new with mySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query for example:

```
Select T1.id_player, T1.id_team_from as Team, T1.Transfer_date as PeriodFrom, 
T2.Transfer_date as PeriodTo
            from  
        (Select id_player,id_team_from, id_team_to, Transfer_date, 
        row_number() over (partition by id_player order by transfer_date desc) RN1)T1
            inner join 
        (Select id_player,id_team_from, id_team_to, Transfer_date, 
        row_number() over (partition by id_player order by transfer_date desc) RN2)T2
            on T1.RN1=T2.RN2+1
            and T1.id_player=T2.id_player
```

It should return all players with teams they played in, from PeriodFrom to PeriodTo.